# tooltip hangs around on canvas after redraw

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas app with a couple normal buttons underneath.  I have tooltips on the buttons, and they seem to work fine under static circumstances.  (I still don't understand why tooltips for disabled buttons appear differently from tooltips for enabled buttons.)

When I hover over an enabled button, its tooltip appears above the button on the canvas surface.  (These are normal jQuery tooltips.)  When the pointer leaves the button, the tooltip goes away.

However, if I push the button (of course the tooltip is showing at that point), my button starts an animated sequence on the canvas, and **the tooltip stays there on the canvas forever**.  Moving the mouse elsewhere doesn't cancel the tooltip after animation starts.  Other tooltips continue to work fine.

In the process of animation I am clearing and redrawing the canvas dozens of times, but the tooltip remains visible, so it is its own rectangle separate from the canvas.

I tried setting the button title to null and empty before redrawing in the animation.  Neither helped.  I'd like to create a synthetic mouseleave for the button, but I don't know how to do that.

This happens on Chrome and Firefox.

Any other thoughts?

**Answer**
As I cut down my substantial program trying to create a small fiddle, as Wolf suggested, I found the source of the problem.

Once you disable a button, it's tooltip won't go away.  If you un-disable the button, the tooltip still doesn't go away.  But if you then hover over the button in the un-disabled state and then un-hover, the tooltip will go away.

Apparently, the code that handles the tooltip (browser?) doesn't process the button tooltip on mouseleave if the button is disabled.  But it will properly process any mouseleave after the button is re-enabled.

I consider this a bug, and I don't see a good workaround.  I can't know whether the tooltip is showing when I want to disable the button.  I will submit it to the jQuery team.

Thank you for listening.

**Workaround**: call $("#buttonid").mouseleave() before disabling button.  The bug appears to be in several browsers, and it may even be called a feature, so it's not likely to be fixed soon.  The workaround has the disadvantage that it makes the user move the pointer to get the tooltip back, so a proper solution in the browsers would be better.  But at least there is a reasonable workaround.

Comment: can you create a fiddle so that we can work on it..

Comment: I don't know what a fiddle is.  I've carved my program down to 32KB in three files.  Is that small enough?  If so, how would I deliver it?

Comment: Just update your code here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Only upload the code required to explain your problem. If the code is less you will get fast response.

Comment: You should learn how to operate on JSFiddle,cause it will help you later on.